# Convert static HTML page to dynamically generated jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, automation

I have an odd requirement where we have static html/css/images.  I then need to convert these static pages into pages that are dynamically generated with javascript/jquery.  We are dealing with 100+ instances of this.

So for example:

```
<div id='foo' title='my title'>Hi there!</div>
```

would be converted to:

```
$('<div/>', {
    id: 'foo',
    title: 'my title',
    text: 'Hi there!'
}).appendTo('#mySelector');
```

Is there a way to do this programmatically?  I googled around but was not able to find anything.

Comment: This seems like a very strange thing to do. You should generally try to do as much as possible with static HTML, and only use Javascript for the parts that need to be generated dynamically, like tables based on runtime data.

Comment: You don't need to use objects like that, you can simply do `$("#mySelector").append("<div id='foo' title='my title'>Hi there!</div>");`. This keeps most of the structure of the original HTML. You may be able to do this with global replace in the editor.

Comment: i know it is odd.  We have an odd requirement.  That is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're asking in the wrong place. Third-party software recommendations are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: You could load a script that parses the `DOM` into a `json` string, and then manually copy and paste that to save your own `.json` file.  From there, you could use JavaScript to load the pieces from the `.json` file you want into the DOM.

Comment: @Alexis Is requirement to create `json` string of `html` text ? javascript `object` of `html` text ? If possible , can describe _"converted to:"_ ? _"static"_ ? Is `html` text within active `document` , or requested from server ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<div></div>

$('div').append('<p></p>');
$('div p').attr({
    'id':'foo',
    'title':'my title'
}).text('Hi there!');
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
<div><p id="foo" title="my title">Hi there!</p></div>
```

Comment: I want to go the other way.  HTML -> JS

Comment: yeah. And I'm looking for a way to automate it